In veeam v12, is the connection useing connect-vbrserver secure?
I have 2 veeam backup servers on separate networks, where each server is managing the backup of the connected infrastructure on its own network. However, for reporting purposes, it is easier to collect all the reports from one server. To get the data of the other network, I use connect-vbrserver and connect to the veeam instance on the other network to get the data for my reports.
I was not able to find any documentation to confirm whether this connection is secure or not, or if it follows the standard PS encryption. I tried to capture packets through wireshark and the data is indeed not human readable, but still looking for hard evidence that this connection is secure. Does anyone have any way to check?
I searched the internet and forums but there were no specific documentation related to this topic in particular (whether security is inherited from PS or from veeam itself).
Also I collected packets from wireshark. The protocol showed TCP (no explicit mention of encryption) although the data was not readable

Veeam uses Cloud Direct : https://www.ibm.com/products/direct-link?utm_content=SRCWW&p1=Search&p4=43700075131024559&p5=e&p9=58700008195583014&gclid=CjwKCAjwtNi0BhA1EiwAWZaANOHPUeLOpZ6fpA7CTY4-B2knpORErt7oD2ZruU6KKwF0g6Zo9KcboxoCObsQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds   See backup storage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veeam_Backup_%26_Replication

Thank you for your comment. However, my question is related to the data transmitted between the backup servers over powershell after starting a session using connect-vbrserver

The link says : Cloud storage support is available on an Infrastructure-as-a-Service (IaaS) model. Veeam's technology, Cloud Connect, provides integrated and secured backup to the cloud through Veeam-powered service providers.[11][12]  It says "service providers"

I may be missing something. But this is talking about cloud storage. I am inquiring about connection through powershell using the connect-vbrserver, between 2 on premise servers that have veeam installed on.

Isn't that Cloud Storage?

no both servers are storing on premise only communicating through powershell.
